# Does the earth revolve, rotate or go (a)round the sun?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-difference

Does the earth revolve, rotate or go (a)round the sun?
What is the correct expression?

Comment: In practice they're all equivalent and equally acceptable / "correct", as is [*The Earth **circles** the Sun.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22earth+circles+the+sun%22)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct verb in this case is 'to revolve'.
So the correct and acceptable expression is:

> The Earth revolves around the sun.

But you can also say "The Earth orbits the sun." or even "The Earth travels around the sun."

The difference between 'to rotate' and 'to revolve' is as follows: rotation means that an object moves around its own axis in a circular movement while revolution (from *revolve*) is when something goes around something else (a smaller body moves around a bigger one). Usually revolution refers only to celestial bodies. Since the Earth travels around much bigger sun in an elliptical trajectory, it is a revolution. Both phenomena, the rotation and the revolution, are described very thoroughly [on this website](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-rotate-and-revolve).

Comment: Celestial bodies [and wheels](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wheel+revolved%2C+wheel+rotated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwheel%20revolved%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwheel%20rotated%3B%2Cc0) and probably other things as well.

Answer (score 2):

Actually technically, the Earth [rotates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_rotation) around it's axis ***while*** it [revolves](http://www.kidsgeo.com/geography-for-kids/0019-the-revolution-of-the-earth.php) around the Sun.

- One rotation per day<sub>*</sub>.
- One revolution per year<sub>*</sub>.

<sub>**Roughly*</sub>